# How can I set the target of this UIBarButton to be another view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

```
UIBarButtonItem* saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                              target:hvc //other controller
                                                                              action:@selector(save:)];
        UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(cancel:)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

I have two buttons being made in a view controller. I'm trying to design the save button to take in the data in some textfields and send it to another view controller, while cancel button just dismisses the current view controller.

Other view controller was initialized in the app delegate file.

How do I define the `target` for the save button to be this other view controller ?

Comment: you want to access the cancel button to another class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the reference to that view controller in the variable `hvc`, then the above code is the way to go. If not get that instance.

However cleaner way is the handle button actions in the displayed view controller only and calling methods of the other view controller from the target handler.

So you will create a method called `-(void)handleSave:(id)data;` and implement it. And call the method using the instance of that view controller class.

Comment: Whether I go with my method or your preferred method, my current view controller needs to have reference to the other view controller, for exmaple when i call 

`[hvc save:...]`

How do give the current controller a reference to the specific instance of the other controller?

Comment: If you creating the second view controller from `hvc` then you can use delegates. Otherwise you can have a method in your codeflow which you give you that instance.